# Function is not defined when I try to get it the data via requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I would like to invoke the saveValue function in every page but I get the below error message.

**Uncaught ReferenceError: saveValue is not defined**

Master page(inline script):

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
   var value = id;
   saveValue(value);
</script>
```

main.js

```
require( 'jquery', 'bootstrap' ], function ($, bootstrap) {
    var saveValue = function (value) {
         window.data.push(saveValue);
    };
});
```

Comment: What comes first, the inline script or loading of the main.js?

Comment: @pjones235 it doesn't matter, `require` is async function, `saveValue(value)` is always called before `saveValue` is defined

Comment: Then I would assume jQuery or Bootstrap doesn't exist at the time the function is called.

Comment: @pjones235 — Which function? `require`? The whole point of `require` is that it loads them. `saveValue`? It is never called, it never exists in the global scope (and won't exist in the local scope of the function passed to `require` until the requirejs has loaded the dependancies.

Comment: Do you have any solution to get the data?